# Unsupported Media Type with HttpClient / .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, http-headers, dotnet-httpclient, http-error

I am working with a RESTful API that supports POST requests in JSON format. The API's own Swagger documentation shows that this is a valid call to one of its endpoints:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '<JSON>' '<URL>'
```

Where `<JSON>` and `<URL>` are the valid JSON message and the endpoint's URL. From this Swagger documentation I gather that any posts to this endpoint must include both a `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers set to `application/json`.

I am writing a C# method that will use .NET Core's `HttpClient` class to post to this endpoint. However, upon posting my message I receive an HTTP 415 error code back, for Unsupported Media Type. From what I've learned so far, the `Content-Type` header must be set in your content (I am using the `StringContent` class) and the `Accept` header can only be set in the `HttpClient` headers. Here is my particular example:

```
var httpContent = new StringContent("<JSON>", Encoding.UTF32, "application/json");
var httpClient = new HttpClient();

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var responseMessage = httpClient.PostAsync("<URL>", httpContent);
var result = responseMessage.Result;
```

Once again, where `<JSON>` and `<URL>` are the valid JSON message and the endpoints's URL. It would seem  to me that the third line, on which I reference `httpCllient.DefaultRequestHeaders`, is not adding the `Accept: application/json` header to my request. If I manually add the header to the `httpContent.Headers` collection, I get a run-time error that tells me that `Accept` is not a header I can add to the `httpContent`. That's why I am hoping to add it to the `httpClient` instead.

I have validated the URL and my JSON with Swagger, so I know those are correct. Also, the request is done over HTTPS, so I can't use Fiddler to validate that the `Accept` header is being included. And while I could enable decryption in Fiddler, that's a whole other ball of wax. I don't want to add their root certificate to my system, especially if I'm missing something fairly simple, which this seems to be.

Any pointers will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why `UTF32`and not `UTF8`?

Comment: Great question. I was not paying attention to the encoding. Changing it to UTF8 solved the issue. Since there is an answer below with the same suggestion, I have accepted it as the answer. Thanks to  both John Wu and Monty.

Comment: I also had this issue when using content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json") in order to satisfy an API. It seems it only accepts the content-type header when included in the StringContent constructor along with the encoding, as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

what about if you try:

```
var httpContent = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

You shouldn't need to add an Accept header.